# Divide a number by 3 without using *, /, +, -, % operators

Tags: code-golf, math, restricted-source, division

Quoting [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11694546/698590) (Spoiler alert!):

> This question has been asked in an Oracle interview.
>
> How would you divide a number by 3 without using *, /, +, -, %,
>   operators?
>
> The number may be signed or unsigned.

The task is solvable, but see if you can write the shortest code.

### Rules:

- Perform the required **integer** division (`/3`)
- Do not use the non-text-based operators `*`, `/`, `+`, `-`, or `%` (or their equivalents, such as `__div__` or `add()`). This also applies to incrementing and decrementing operators, like `i++` or `i--`. Use of operators for string concatenation and formatting are OK. Using these characters for different operators, such as unary `-` operator for negative numbers, or `*` to represent a pointer in C is OK as well.
- Input value can be arbitrarily large (whatever your system can handle), both positive and negative
- Input can be on STDIN or ARGV or entered any other way
- Create the shortest code you can to do the above

Comment: How should the result be rounded when positive? How when negative?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## J, <s>45 44</s>  10 chars

`".,&'r3'":`

Works with negatives:

```
".,&'r3'": 15
5
   ".,&'r3'": _9
_3
   ".,&'r3'": 3e99
1e99
```

`":` - format as text

`,&'r3'` - append `r3` to the end

`".` - execute the string, e.g. `15r3`

Comment: what is the '%' operator in J mean?  same with '+', '/'?

Comment: @acolyte Thanks for reminding.. I think I've fixed code now. `-.` is matrix subtraction - is this allowed?

Comment: i have no idea haha.

Comment: I don't think this qualifies because of the `%` and `+`. The `%` you can replace by using `0.333333` but you'll still have the problem of your addition. Possibly though you could look into the [Base](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d401.htm) and [Antibase](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d402.htm) (`#:`, `#.`) operators to reproduce the method you use in your Ruby solution?

Comment: @Gareth Sorry, wrong rollback it was.

Comment: Ah, I see. Clever. I think you're probably ok with the `-.` for removing values from the set.

Comment: @Gareth #: is #. behaves strangely to me, I can't understand the logic. I mean with base 2 it works clear, but base 3.. `3 #. 1 0 0` -> `9` -- ok, but.. `3 #: 9` -> `0` -- why?

Comment: It works if you do `3 3 3 #: 9`. It looks like you need to know how long your ternary number will be. `_3]\i.` is also a possible starting point for something, but I don't know if it would be shorter than your solution here. The problem with `#_3]\i.` as it stands is that it always rounds up instead of down.

Comment: Maybe `##~3=_3#\i.` for 11 characters?

Comment: Actually, you can shrink yours down to 10 characters with `##~0 0 1$~`.

Comment: @Gareth nice one!

Comment: @Gareth I've come up with almost direct translation from Ruby version `3 :'3#.}:(($&3)y)#:y'` but it doesn't handle negative values unlike Ruby version.

Comment: You can shrink that down using a hook to `3#.}:(#:~$&3)` but it's still longer and it doesn't fix the negative number issue.

Comment: @Gareth updated, now works for negs. But is there a shorter form of flow control in J? Of course I can use `*&y*t` to determine the sign of the `y` and multiply but it's against the rules

Comment: Yes, you can use either the [Power function](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d202n.htm) `^:` or [Agenda](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d621.htm) `@.` for an `if` or `if...else` replacement. In this case you might be able to use `@.` with two verbs connected with a '`' character (a gerund in J-speak) to select one or the other based on a condition.

Comment: You can turn it into 2 lines like this: `t=.[:#[:#~0 0 1$~]` `t\`([:-[:t|)@.(0>])` for 36 characters (37 including the newline). You may be able to make it shorter using `3 :'...'`.

Comment: `(]\`(0-])@.(0>[)#@(#~0 0 1$~|))` for 30 characters.

Comment: @Gareth I haven't catch the `@.` thing completely yet, but I used `(condition){(v1,v2)` instead. We've beat my ruby solution by 1 char, hehe

Comment: On the other hand we can't use `-` here, so I replaced it with `<:^:(n)0`

Comment: Nice, never considered using `{`.

Comment: how is this supposed to work? like compile or something? somebody help please. Thanks

Comment: +Chui you just enter this line in the j console (repl)

Comment: Using J's rational 1/3 with an eval is dangerously close to just using `%3` -- imo it's a technicality to say it's not using division directly...

Answer (score 58):

## C, 167503724710

Here's my solution to the problem. I admit it is unlikely to win a strict code golf competition, but it doesn't use any tricks to indirectly call built-in division functionality, it is written in portable C (as the original Stack Overflow question asked for), it works perfectly for negative numbers, and the code is exceptionally clear and explicit.

My program is the *output* of the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

# 71
sys.stdout.write('''#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int32_t div_by_3(int32_t input){''')

# 39 * 2**32
for i in range(-2**31, 2**31):
    # 18 + 11 + 10 = 39
    sys.stdout.write('if(input==%11d)return%10d;' % (i, i / 3))

# 95
sys.stdout.write(r'''return 7;}int main(int c,char**v){int32_t n=atoi(a[1]);printf("%d / 3 = %d\n",n, div_by_3(n));}''')
```

Character count: 71 + 39 * 2**32 + 95 = **167503724710**

#### Benchmarks

It was asked how long this would take and how much memory it would use, so here are some benchmarks:

- Script execution time — Running `./test.py | pv --buffer-size=1M --average-rate > /dev/null` for about 30 seconds gives a rate of about 14.8 MB/s. The rate of output can reasonably be assumed to be roughly constant, so the running time to completion should be about 167503724710 B / (14.8 * 1048576 B/s) ≈ 10794 s.
- Compilation time — The TCC compiler [claims to compile C code at 29.6 MB/s](http://bellard.org/tcc/#speed), which makes for a compilation time of 167503724710 B / (29.6 * 1048576 B/s) ≈ 5397 s. (Of course this can run in a pipeline with the script.)
- Size of compiled code — I tried estimating it using `./test.py | tcc -c - -o /dev/stdout | pv --buffer-size=1M --average-rate > /dev/null`, but it seems `tcc` doesn't output anything until it reads the entire source file in.
- Memory usage to run — Since the algorithm is linear (and tcc doesn't optimize across lines), the memory overhead should be only a few kilobytes (apart from the code itself, of course).

Comment: This is the epitome of hardcoding. ++++++++++

Comment: That being said, I'm sure if you gave them a 160 GB source file and asked them to compile and test it, they'd look at you like you were crazy.

Comment: If my boss asked me to compute a division by three without - + / * % I would think he's crazy.

Comment: And yet, `a[b]` is a syntactic sugar for `*(a + b)`, which does the addition.

Comment: You did not give an answer. You say that your answer is the output of a program. So you should give the output, not the program.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco There is a size restriction on Stack Exchange answers.

Comment: How about outputting the assembly?

Comment: You can speed it up by hardcoding binary search using a tree of nested ifs, with bitwise `&` to optimize the comparison against a power of two.

Answer (score 40):

## Ruby 28

```ruby
b=->n{n.to_s(3).chop.to_i 3}
```

To divide by 3 we just need to remove the trailing zero in base 3 number:
`120 -> 11110 -> 1111 -> 40`

Works with negatives:

```
ice distantstar:~/virt/golf [349:1]% ruby ./div3.rb
666
222
ice distantstar:~/virt/golf [349]% ruby ./div3.rb
-15        
-5
```

## Ruby, <s>60</s>45

Alternatively, w/o using base conversion:

<s>d=->n{x=n.abs;r=(0..1.0/0).step(3).take(x).index x;n>0?r:-r}</s>

```
d=->n{(r=1.step(n.abs,3).to_a.size);n>0?r:-r}
```

Comment: The alternate without base conversion has the banned `/` operator where `Float::INFINITY` became `1.0/0`. With Ruby 2.1, one may golf `(0..1.0/0).step(3)` into `0.step(p,3)`, removing the `/`. The bigger problem is that `-r` uses `-` to negate. It costs 5 characters to change `-r` to `~r.pred`, abusing *Integer#pred* to subtract 1 without the subtraction operator.

Answer (score 27):

## Mathematica, 13 chars

```
Mean@{#,0,0}&
```

Comment: This is wicked :D  I guess you could save the `&` and use a plain variable (others here do that too).

Comment: @YvesKlett: Mean is inherently wicked.

Answer (score 18):

### JavaScript, 56

```
alert(Array(-~prompt()).join().replace(/,,,/g,1).length)
```

Makes a string of length `n` of repeating `,`s and replaces `,,,` with `1`. Then, it measures the string's resulting length. (Hopefully unary `-` is allowed!)

Comment: +1 but it doesn't work with negative values

Comment: Uh, question... how does this count? It uses the `-` negation operator.

Comment: @Patrick I took the specification to mean no subtraction -- if you want, you can replace `-~` with `parseInt()`

Comment: @CaseyChu the value returned by `-~prompt()` is one greater than `parseInt(prompt())`. Not sure how you'd deal with that.

Comment: `alert(Array(parseInt(prompt())).slice(1).join().replace(/,,,/g,1).length)`

Comment: @CaseyChu, I said one _greater_, not one less.

Comment: You could do `alert((Array(parseInt(prompt()))+",").replace(/,,,/g,1).length)`.

Comment: @ETHproductions then you are using the also blacklisted + operator

Comment: @ShaunH `+` is allowed for string concatenation.

Comment: Instead of using alert, you can use `f=>Rest Of Code`, as an anonymous function

Answer (score 16):

### Python, <strike>41</strike> 38

```
print"-"[x:]+`len(xrange(2,abs(x),3))`
```

`xrange` seems to be able to handle large numbers (I think the limit is the same as for a long in C) almost instantly.

```
>>> x = -72
-24

>>> x = 9223372036854775806
3074457345618258602
```

Comment: `10/3` equals 3, not 4.

Comment: Doing `print" -"[x<0]+`len(range(2,abs(x),3))`` will shave it down to 39 chars

Comment: golfexchange's comment formatting is messing it up. on the above I used backticks to enclose `len()` as shorthand for `repr()`

Comment: I've updated it. I can't use `range`, because it will actually create the list. `xrange` just pretends to, so it is able to handle huge numbers without wasting time/memory.

Comment: Pretend it's Python 3 ;) I like the single char slicing btw.

Answer (score 11):

### Haskell, 90 <del>106</del>

```
d n=snd.head.dropWhile((/=n).fst)$zip([0..]>>=ν)([0..]>>=replicate 3>>=ν);ν q=[negate q,q]
```

Creates an infinite (lazy) lookup list `[(0,0),(0,0),(-1,0),(1,0),(-2,0),(2,0),(-3,-1),(3,1), ...]`, trims all elements that don't match `n` (`/=` is inequality in Haskell) and returns the first which does.

This gets much simpler if there are no negative numbers:

### 25 <del>27</del>

```
(([0..]>>=replicate 3)!!)
```

simply returns the `n`th element of the list `[0,0,0,1,1,1,2, ...]`.

Comment: o.O  i never thought of that second solution.  I might be able to implement something like that in python

Answer (score 8):

### C#,  232 bytes

My first code golf... And since there wasn't any C# and I wanted to try a different method not tried here, thought I would give it a shot. Like some others here, only non-negative numbers.

```
class l:System.Collections.Generic.List<int>{}class p{static void Main(string[] g){int n=int.Parse(g[0]);l b,a=new l();b=new l();while(a.Count<n)a.Add(1);while(a.Count>2){a.RemoveRange(0,3);b.Add(1);}System.Console.Write(b.Count);}}
```

### Ungolfed

```
class l : System.Collections.Generic.List<int>
{ }
class p
{
    static void Main(string[] g)
    {
        int n = int.Parse(g[0]);
        l b, a = new l();
        b = new l();
        while (a.Count < n) a.Add(1);
        while (a.Count > 2)
        {
            a.RemoveRange(0, 3);
            b.Add(1);
        }
        System.Console.Write(b.Count);
    }
}
```

Comment: About 5 years later.. You can save 1 byte by removing the space from `string[] g`, turning it into `string[]g`

Comment: Quoting "Do not use the non-text-based operators *, /, +, -, or % (or their equivalents, such as div or add()" -- are you not using an equivalent -- `.Add`?

Comment: @JonathanFrech That add method does not work on two numbers, it only adds a value to a collection

Answer (score 7):

### Perl (<del>26</del> 22)

```
$_=3x pop;say s|333||g
```

This version (ab)uses Perl's regex engine. It reads a number as the last command line argument (`pop`) and builds a string of `3`s of this length (`"3" x $number`). The regex substitution operator (`s///`, here written with different delimitiers because of the puzzle's rules and with a `g`lobal flag) substitues three characters by the empty string and returns the number of substitutions, which is the input number integer-divided by three. It could even be written without `3`, but the above version looks funnier.

```
$ perl -E '$_=3x pop;say s|333||g' 42
14
```

Comment: Hey @memowe, nice work! You could save a few more chars (4) by doing `$_=3x pop;say s|333||g`.

Comment: When the input is 0, 1, or 2, then it prints an empty string. If it needs to print 0, then it needs 3 more characters (25 total): `'$_=3x pop;say s|333||g||0`. Slow with large numbers like 99999999, and doesn't work with negative numbers.

Comment: Use `-p` on the commandline, and you can do: `$_=3x$_;$_=0|s|...||g` for a total of 22, including coverage of the 0, 1, or 2 inputs.

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript, 55

```
alert(parseInt((~~prompt()).toString(3).slice(0,-1),3))
```

If one can't use `-1`, then here is a version replacing it with `~0` (thanks Peter Taylor!).

```
alert(parseInt((~~prompt()).toString(3).slice(0,~0),3))
```

Comment: What does `~~` mean in javascript?

Comment: @ArtemIce One `~` is a Bitwise operator which inverts the bits of the operand (first converting it to a number). This is the shortest way to convert a string to a number (as far as I know).

Comment: I feel like using string parsing/conversion is cheating, since its a) a very complicated and expensive process compared to bitwise operations, b) uses the forbidden operators internally, and c) would take up waaaaay more characters than a homerolled solution.  Kind of like how people get grumpy when you use the built in sorts when asked to implement a quicksort.

Comment: @Inkbug, I think you can also use the unary `+` operator as a slightly shorter way to coerce a string into a number.

Comment: @Sam While "text-based" `+` is allowed, I'm not sure that using it to convert a string to a number is allowed.

Comment: @Sam Also, `~~` converts to an integer, as opposed to `+`.

Comment: @Wug It is codegolf, thus it's not about efficiency unless specified in the task.

Comment: @ArtemIce If someone rolled their own string parser to do it that would be fine, but there's no challenge if you just use the languages build in parsing.  This is the point I was trying to make with the sorting analogy.

Comment: @Inkbug, yes, now I can see why you used ~~. I should have paid more attention before commenting.

Comment: +1 for taking advantage of different bases. It's one of my favorite JavaScript golf techniques.

Comment: Bravo! This deserves more upvotes! It works with positive and negative.

Answer (score 6):

## Python 42

```
int(' -'[x<0]+str(len(range(2,abs(x),3))))
```

Since every solution posted here that Ive checked truncates decimals here is my solution that does that.

## Python <strike>50</strike> 51

```
int(' -'[x<0]+str(len(range([2,0][x<0],abs(x),3))))
```

Since python does floor division, here is my solution that implements that.

Input integer is in the variable x.

Tested in Python 2.7 but I suspect it works in 3 as well.

Comment: +1 For offering both alternatives to the negative value situation. Since there are already so many answers, I'll not be adjusting the spec to exclude one or the other option, though I would personally agree that `-3` is the correct answer to `-10/3`.

Comment: For those who care about floor division in python:
http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html

Comment: what's with the multiplication and subtraction in your second solution?

Comment: @boothby The second solution implements floor division. I wanted to do range(0,abs(x),3) for negative numbers and range(2,abs(x),3) for positive numbers. In order to do that I had range(2... then i subtracted 2 when x is negative. X<0 is True when x is negative, (True)*2 == 2

Comment: I'm not understanding the difference between floor division and truncating decimals. Does this have to with negative division?

Comment: @JoelCornett Yes, if your division truncates decimals the result is the same as float division, then you round toward zero. Floor division is when your result is the same as float division, but then you round down. For positive results these are the same, for negative results they are not.

Comment: @Matt, `print` starts with `pr` and the challenge says not to use `+-/*`.

Comment: @boothby yes, print does start with pr, but I do not believe that the challenge required us to print the result, it just said we should calculate it. You are right about +-/* though, I forgot about that temporarily. I shall have to revise that answer.

Answer (score 6):

### C, 160 chars

Character by character long division solution using lookup tables, i.e. without string atoi() or printf() to convert between base 10 strings and integers.

Output will sometimes include a leading zero - part of it's charm.

```
main(int n,char**a){
char*s=a[1],*x=0;
if(*s==45)s=&s[1];
for(;*s;s=&s[1])n=&x[*s&15],x="036"[(int)x],*s=&x["000111222333"[n]&3],x="012012012012"[n]&3;
puts(a[1]);
}
```

Note:

- abuses array access to implement addition.
- compiles with clang 4.0, other compilers may barf.

Testing:

```
./a.out -6            -2
./a.out -5            -1
./a.out -4            -1
./a.out -3            -1
./a.out -2            -0
./a.out -1            -0
./a.out 0             0
./a.out 1             0
./a.out 2             0
./a.out 3             1
./a.out 4             1
./a.out 5             1
./a.out 6             2
./a.out 42            14
./a.out 2011          0670
```

Answer (score 6):

## C 83 characters

The number to divide is passed in through stdin, and it returns it as the exit code from `main()` (%ERRORLEVEL% in CMD). This code abuses some versions of MinGW in that when optimizations aren't on, it treats the last assignment value as a return statement. It can probably be reduced a bit. Supports all numbers that can fit in to an `int`

If unary negate (-) is not permitted: (129)

```
I(unsigned a){a=a&1?I(a>>1)<<1:a|1;}main(a,b,c){scanf("%i",&b);a=b;a=a<0?a:I(~a);for(c=0;a<~1;a=I(I(I(a))))c=I(c);b=b<0?I(~c):c;}
```

If unary negate **IS** permitted: (123)

```
I(unsigned a){a=a&1?I(a>>1)<<1:a|1;}main(a,b,c){scanf("%i",&b);a=b;a=a<0?a:-a;for(c=0;a<~1;a=I(I(I(a))))c=I(c);b=b<0?-c:c;}
```

## EDIT: ugoren pointed out to me that -~ is an increment...

83 Characters if unary negate is permitted :D

```
main(a,b,c){scanf("%i",&b);a=b;a=a<0?a:-a;for(c=0;a<~1;a=-~-~-~a)c=-~c;b=b<0?-c:c;}
```

Comment: If unary negate is permitted, `x+3` is `-~-~-~x`.

Comment: Thank you for that. I don't know why that never occurred to me. I guess I didn't realize you could stack unaries so gratuitously hehe.

Answer (score 5):

## C, 139 chars

```
t;A(a,b){return a?A((a&b)<<1,a^b):b;}main(int n,char**a){n=atoi(a[1]);for(n=A(n,n<0?2:1);n&~3;t=A(n>>2,t),n=A(n>>2,n&3));printf("%d\n",t);}
```

Run with number as command line argument

- Handles both negative and positive numbers

Testing:

```
 ./a.out -6            -2
 ./a.out -5            -1
 ./a.out -4            -1
 ./a.out -3            -1
 ./a.out -2            0
 ./a.out -1            0
 ./a.out 0             0
 ./a.out 1             0
 ./a.out 2             0
 ./a.out 3             1
 ./a.out 4             1
 ./a.out 5             1
 ./a.out 6             2
 ./a.out 42            14
 ./a.out 2011          670
```

Edits:

- saved 10 chars by shuffling addition (A) to remove local variables.

Comment: Nicely done. I tried my best at bit twiddling and got to 239. I just can't get my head around your `A`, my function just checks the bit i in number n. Does C standard allow omitting type declarations or is that some compiler thing?

Comment: C will assume int if unspecified.

Answer (score 5):

### C, <strike>81</strike> 73 chars

Supports non-negative numbers only.

```
char*x,*i;
main(){
    for(scanf("%d",&x);x>2;x=&x[~2])i=&i[1];
    printf("%d",i);
}
```

The idea is to use pointer arithemtic. The number is read into the pointer `x`, which doesn't point anywhere. `&x[~2]` = `&x[-3]` = `x-3` is used to subtract 3. This is repeated as long as the number is above 2. `i` counts the number of times this is done (`&i[1]` = `i+1`).

Comment: Trying to understand the code,somebody shed some lights? Thanks

Comment: @Chui, added explanation.

Comment: @ugoren as far as I understand, shouldn't printf("%d") print out the memory address pointer i holds in Hex? why it is printing out an integer? or char* i was initialized to point to memory address 0 by default? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

### ZSH — <del>31</del> 20/21

```
echo {2..x..3}|wc -w
```

For negative numbers:

```
echo {-2..x..3}|wc -w
```

#### With negative numbers (ZSH + `bc`) — <del>62</del> 61

I probably shouldn't give two programs as my answer, so here's one that works for any sign of number:

```
echo 'obase=10;ibase=3;'`echo 'obase=3;x'|bc|sed 's/.$//'`|bc
```

This uses the same base conversion trick as [Artem Ice's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6838/1136).

Answer (score 5):

### Java <del>86</del> 79

Assume the integer is in y:

Converts to a string in base 3, 
removes the last character ( right shift ">>" in base 3 ), 
then converts back to integer.

Works for negative numbers.

If the number, y, is < 3 or > -3, then it gives 0.

```
System.out.print(~2<y&y<3?0:Long.valueOf(Long.toString(y,3).split(".$")[0],3));
```

First time posting on code golf. =) So can't comment yet.

Thx Kevin Cruijssen for the tips.

Comment: I know it's been more than two years ago, but you can golf a few parts: `&&` to `&`, and 2x `Integer` to `Long`. (Also, why do you use `~2` instead of just `-3`? They are the same byte-count.)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen So nostalgic to edit my first post after so long. Wasn't too sure why I thought ~2 was better back then.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen well, the challenge says you're not allowed to use `-`, but I don't know if that counts for unary negation.

Comment: @FlipTack Ah you're completely right. In that case forget I ever said it. :)

Answer (score 4):

## Python2.6 (<s>29</s>)(<s>71</s>)(<s>57</s>)(<s>52</s>)(43)

```
z=len(range(2,abs(x),3))
print (z,-z)[x<0]
```

```
print len(range(2,input(),3))
```

Edit - Just realized that we have to handle negative integers too. Will fix that later

Edit2 - Fixed

Edit3 - Saved 5 chars by following Joel Cornett's advice

Edit4 - Since input doesn't have to be necessarily be from STDIN or ARGV, saved 9 chars by not taking any input from stdin

Comment: Go ahead with `abs()`

Comment: shorter to do `print z if x==abs(x) else -z`

Comment: better yet, `print (z,-z)[x<0]`

Comment: @ArtemIce thanks, only realized I could use that after reading another answer above.

Comment: @JoelCornett humm, didn't know about that, thanks

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript, <s>47</s> 29

Uses `eval` to dynamically generate a `/`. Uses `+` only for string concatenation, not addition.

```
alert(eval(prompt()+"\57"+3))
```

EDIT: Used `"\57"` instead of `String.fromCharCode(47)`

Comment: -1 for `alert(eval(prompt()+"\573"))`?

Answer (score 4):

### Ruby (<s>43</s> <s>22</s> 17)

Not only golf, but elegance also :)

```
p Rational gets,3
```

Output will be like `(41/1)`. If it must be integer then we must add `.to_i` to result, and if we change `to_i` to `to_f` then we will can get output for floats also.

Comment: Works without the require `rational` line on Ruby 1.9.3. Omitting the parentheses saves [one more char](http://ideone.com/vmOWj7).

Answer (score 4):

## TI-Basic, 8 bytes

Winner? :)

```
int(mean({Ans,0,0
```

P.S. Rounds towards infinity for negative numbers (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19517868/integer-division-by-negative-number) for why). To round to zero instead, replace `int(` with `iPart(` for no byte change.

**Test cases**

```
-4:prgmDIVIDE
              -2
11:prgmDIVIDE
               3
109:prgmDIVIDE
              36
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2.x, <s>54</s> <s>53</s> 51

`print' -'[x<0],len(range(*(2,-2,x,x,3,-3)[x<0::2]))`

Where `_` is the dividend and is entered as such.

```
>>> x=-19
>>> print' -'[x<0],len(range(*(2,-2,x,x,3,-3)[x<0::2]))
- 6
```

Note: Not sure if using the interactive interpreter is allowed, but according to the OP: "Input can be on STDIN or ARGV or entered any other way"

Edit: Now for python 3 (works in 2.x, but prints a tuple). Works with negatives.

Comment: Works in python 3 as well?

Comment: Doesn't have to be subscriptable; having `__len__` is enough.

Comment: `len(range(100,1000))` gives `900` in 3.2.3 on linux.

Comment: This doesn't work for negative numbers. And `len(xrange(0,_,3))` is shorter and massively faster anyway.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail: Point taken. I concede. It does work on 3.

Comment: @grc: Edited based on your comment. Still working on the negative number thing.

Answer (score 3):

### C++, 191

With main and includes, its 246, without main and includes, it's only 178.  Newlines count as 1 character.  Treats all numbers as unsigned.  I don't get warnings for having main return an unsigned int so its fair game.

My first ever codegolf submission.

```
#include<iostream>
#define R return
typedef unsigned int U;U a(U x,U y){R y?a(x^y,(x|y^x^y)<<1):x;}U d(U i){if(i==3)R 1;U t=i&3,r=i>>=2;t=a(t,i&3);while(i>>=2)t=a(t,i&3),r=a(r,i);R r&&t?a(r,d(t)):0;}U main(){U i;std::cin>>i,std::cout<<d(i);R 0;}
```

uses shifts to divide number by 4 repeatedly, and calculates sum (which converges to 1/3)

Pseudocode:

```
// typedefs and #defines for brevity

function a(x, y):
    magically add x and y using recursion and bitwise things
    return x+y.

function d(x):
    if x = 3:
        return 1.
    variable total, remainder
    until x is zero:
        remainder = x mod 4
        x = x / 4
        total = total + x
    if total and remainder both zero:
        return 0.
    else:
        return a(total, d(remainder)).
```

As an aside, I could eliminate the main method by naming d main and making it take a char ** and using the programs return value as the output.  It will return the number of command line arguments divided by three, rounded down.  This brings its length to the advertised 191:

```
#define R return
typedef unsigned int U;U a(U x,U y){R y?a(x^y,(x|y^x^y)<<1):x;}U main(U i,char**q){if(i==3)R 1;U t=i&3,r=i>>=2;t=a(t,i&3);while(i>>=2)t=a(t,i&3),r=a(r,i);R r&&t?a(r,d(t)):0;}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Golfscript - 13 chars

```
~3base);3base
```

Comment: doesn't seem to handle negative input

Comment: @r.e.s. `s/seem to //` :(. I'll have to have a think about it

Answer (score 3):

### **PowerShell 57 or 46**

In 57 characters using `%` as the PowerShell foreach operator, not modulo. This solution can accept positive or negative integers.

```
(-join(1..(Read-Host)|%{1})-replace111,0-replace1).Length
```

In 46 characters if `*` is allowed as the string repetition operator, not multiply. This option requires positive integers as input values.

```
("1"*(Read-Host)-replace111,0-replace1).Length
```

Comment: [If you ever come back, I posted a bug fix.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/187333/78849) If you want me to delete mine and incorporate the change into yours, just let me know.

Answer (score 3):

## R

These only work with positive integers:

```
max(sapply(split(1:x,1:3), length))
# Gives a warning that should be ignored
```

Or:

```
min(table(rep(1:3, x)[1:x]))
```

Or:

```
length((1:x)[seq(3,x,3)])
```

Or:

```
sum(rep(1,x)[seq(3,x,3)])
```

[[EDIT]] And an ugly one:

```
trunc(sum(rep(0.3333333333, x)))
```

[[EDIT2]] Plus probably the best one - inspired by the matlab code above by Elliot G:

```
length(seq(1,x,3))
```

Comment: I wanted to implement the same idea as in your EDIT2 but it does not work for negative numbers: `wrong sign in 'by' argument `

Answer (score 3):

## SmileBASIC, <s>58</s> <s>51</s> 36 bytes (no mathematical functions!)

```
INPUT N
BGANIM.,4,-3,N
WAIT?BGROT(0)
```

Explanation:

```
INPUT N           'get input
BGANIM 0,"R",-3,N 'smoothly rotate background layer 0 by N degrees over 3 frames
WAIT              'wait 1 frame
PRINT BGROT(0)    'display angle of layer 0
```

The program moves the background layer smoothly over 3 frames, and then gets the angle after 1 frame, when it has traveled 1/3 of its total distance.

#### Float division version, 38 bytes:

```
INPUT N
BGANIM.,7,-3,N
WAIT?BGVAR(0,7)
```

Explanation:

```
INPUT N           'input
BGANIM 0,"V",-3,N 'smoothly change layer 0's internal variable to N over 3 frames
WAIT              'wait 1 frame
PRINT BGVAR(0,7)  'display layer 0's internal variable
```

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell <s>41</s> 39 chars

Works with the full set of positive and negative integers

```
f n=sum[sum$1:[-2|n<0]|i<-[3,6..abs n]]
```

First creates a list 1's or (-1)'s (depending on the sign of the input) for every third integer from 0 up until the input `n`. `abs(n)` for negative numbers inclusive.

e.g `n=8 -> [0,3,6]`

It then returns the sum of this list.

Comment: Doesn't work on negative numbers (-3/3 is -1 not 1).

Comment: Nice you made it work on negative numbers but you can't use /, read the specification.

Comment: Oh gosh, you got me twice. All fixed ;)

Comment: Nice! Btw You can get 39 chars with
    f n=sum[sum$1:[-2|n<0]|i<-[3,6..abs n]]

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 72 bytes

```python
f=lambda x:x and s(x>>1,f(x>>1))
s=lambda x,y:y and s(x^y,(~x&y)<<1)or x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYwxCsMwDAB3v0JoKBYIgjF0MEmeUnBI3QpaJTgZ7KVfd0KhXe6W49a6Pxf1raXhFd/THKGEAlFn2GwZR8fpKyKz/QOuof6SW2X7KZdKfe9oyVBaOikgCjnq427dlYIBWLPoboWxAw8DnlshRossnWckJNMO)

A bitwise solution consisting of two recursive functions, one to calculate third, the other to subtract. Because multiplying and dividing by 2 is easy to do bitwise, we can use the fact:
\$X/3=X/2-(X/2)/3\$
to recursively find the third.

It does produce some weird rounding patterns for non-multiples of three.

```python
0 -> 0 (0)
1 -> 0 (0.333...)
2 -> 1 (0.666...)
3 -> 1 (1)
4 -> 1 (1.333...)
5 -> 1 (1.666...)
6 -> 2 (2)
7 -> 2 (2.333...)
8 -> 3 (2.666...)
9 -> 3 (3)
10 -> 4 (3.333...)
11 -> 4 (3.666...)
12 -> 4 (4)
13 -> 4 (4.333...)
14 -> 5 (4.666...)
15 -> 5 (5)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure, 87; works with negatives; based on lazyseqs

```clojure
(defn d[n](def r(nth(apply interleave(repeat 3(range)))(Math/abs n)))(if(> n 0)r(- r)))
```

Ungolfed:

```clojure
(defn d [n]
  (let [r (nth (->> (range) (repeat 3) (apply interleave))
               (Math/abs n))]
        (if (pos? n)
          r
          (- r))))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica <strike>36 51</strike> 42 chars

This is easily achieved in base 3.

`IntegerDigits[n,3]` converts the absolute value of the number to base 3.

`Most` takes all but the rightmost digit. This "rightward shift" amounts to integer division by 3.

`FromDigits` converts back to base 10.

`Sign` restores, if necessary, the sign.

```
Sign@n*Most@IntegerDigits[n,3]~FromDigits~3
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Sage Notebook](http://www.sagemath.org/)   (21)

```
ZZ(n.digits(3)[1:],3)
```

Answer (score 2):

## F# (81)

Using inclusive ranges:

```
let(^)s x=if s<0 then int("-"+string x)else x
let d m =sign m^[3..3..abs m].Length
```

Alternatively, using strings:

```
let (^) s x = if s < 0 then int("-" + string x) else x
let d m =
  let n = abs m
  [0..n]
  |> Seq.map (fun i -> i, String.replicate i "aaa")
  |> Seq.takeWhile (fun (i, s) -> s.Length <= n)
  |> Seq.last
  |> fst
  |> (^) (sign m)
```

This is verbose but it's better than being forced to use loops in many imperative languages. `String.replicate` is especially valuable.

Comment: This looks like it uses multiplication `*` to restore the sign bit.

Answer (score 2):

## APL (NARS2000), 7 characters

[Inspiration](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6991/43319)

```
⍎⍞,'r3'
```

`⍎` evaluate

`⍞` text input

`,'r3'` followed by "r3"

So "15" becomes "15r3" which is NARS2000's rational point notation and evaluates to 5.

Note that the OP states

> - Input can be on STDIN or ARGV or entered any other way
> - Create the shortest code you can to do the above

which allows me to take input as string, and count code length in characters (not bytes – as this is a fairly old challenge that predates the adoption of bytes as default code length unit).

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
3B¨3ö
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=M0LCqDPDtg&input=Ng)

Answer (score 2):

## C# with Linq, 51 Bytes

```
using System.Linq;(n)=>(int)new[]{n,0,0}.Average();
```

Unfortunately much longer than the Mathematica version of this approach (pesky using statement), but pretty good for C#.

[Try it out here.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/k5yLzn)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>72 69 59</s> 58 bytes

```c
a,q;f(x){for(a=q=0;a=-~-~-~a,a<=abs(x);)q=-~q;x=x<0?-q:q;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FclLCoAwDADRuxSEBFoo4soYPEusVFz4ibooiF69VmY3L7gphJzFKkVIeMftAGFlT8Lu/RMrHctwFiXUMpUSp873TlulJy8yr4D3fszrFcFUo7ERXFMjFvwA)

Edit: Now works with negative arguments.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>62</s> <s>52</s> 41 Chars

```
f n=sum[last$1:[-1|n<0]|i<-[3,6..abs(n)]]
```

If using sum is not allowed, here's a 52 char solution:

```
f n|n>0=s|1>0=(-s)where s=length[1|i<-[3,6..abs(n)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

### Scala 96

```
def d(x:Int)={val y=x.abs;val r=0.to(y).flatMap(List.fill(3)(_)).drop(y).head;if(x==y)r else -r}
```

I do realize now it is basically the same idea behind some other answers here ([Haskell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6865/9137), [Clojure](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6902/9137) and the 2nd take of this one in [Ruby](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6838/9137), to name a few)... :-/

Answer (score 1):

### C++ 633 byes (including whitespace; 457 bytes excluding scaffolding)

I know this is not anywhere near the shortest code, but it does have some "advantages". First the code:

```
#include <climits>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;typedef int I;typedef unsigned U;U A(U l,U r){U t;while(r)t=l^r,r=(l&r)<<1,l=t;return l;}
#define N(l)A(~l,1)
#define S(l,r)A(l,N(r))
U M(U l, U r){U p=0;while(r){if(r&1)p=A(p,l);l<<=1;r>>=1;}return p;}U D(U n,U&r){U m=U(1)<<S(M(sizeof(U),CHAR_BIT),1),q=r=0,x=1;while(x){q<<=1;r<<=1;if(n&m)r|=1;if(r>=3)q|=1,r=S(r,3);n<<=1;x<<=1;}return q;}I D(I n,I&r){bool o=n<0;U p=o?N(n):n,s,t;s=D(p,t);r=o?N(t):t;return o?N(s):s;}I main(I c,char**v){I i=1,q,r;while(i<c)q=D(atoi(v[i]),r),cout<<v[i]<<" divided by 3 == "<<q<<" with a remainder of "<<r<<endl,i=A(i,1);}
```

The advantages over the other solutions, even though it can't win on a purely codegolf basis:

- It only uses the standard library to obtain the value of CHAR_BIT, atoi, cout, and endl. Consequently, it does not depend on any math routines in the standard library beyond those to convert a string to and from a number. It most definitely does not use any part of the standard library to divide by 3.
- It at no time uses any of the operators + - * / % (binary or unary, numeric or string). Note that it does use two asterisks to declare a pointer to a pointer to char, but it only uses that to access command line parameters of number to divide.
- It uses bit manipulation and relational operators exclusively in the division process.
- If the scaffolding code (main and two of the three include files) is removed, the code that does the actual work of division by 3 is only 457 bytes.
- I'm pretty sure this code should work on any C++ compiler conforming to the standard and does not exploit any tricks that only work on a subset of compilers or platforms. One possible exception to this is it might not work on a platform that does not use twos complement signed integers, though I don't have access to any platform like that to test that theory. Another possible exception (related) is if automatic signed / unsigned conversions are not supported as they are for most (or all) platforms utilizing twos complement signed integers.

I'm sure there are other ways to make this shorter, but I've spent enough time on it. Mainly I wanted to perform the exercise without any "cheating" via use of any operations from the standard library. By defining functions and macros that perform unary negation, addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division strictly in terms of bit level operations and relational operators, signed (or unsigned) integers can be divided by three. I've hard coded the divisor to 3 to remove a few bytes of code here and there, though adding a parameter to pass in the divisor is fairly trivial.

The signed division function notes the sign of the dividend then calls the unsigned division function with the dividends absolute value. Once the unsigned division returns the unsigned quotient and remainder, the original sign is used to negate the signed quotient and remainder as needed.

Edit: Only after I wrote and submitted my solution did I go look at the original question on SO. Some interesting stuff there, and of course someone had already come up with my solution. FWIW, I did write this on my own! Not that it matters for this old of a question, especially in a codegolf exercise. :)

Answer (score 1):

**OCTAVE/MATLAB 13**

Code where x is an integer. Only works for positive integers and rounds the result up.

```
length(1:3:x)
```

Comment: You could replace `length` with `nnz`

Answer (score 1):

### Java 317

I know this is extremely long, and I know this is supposed to be code golf, but for kicks I wanted to write a version that ALSO:

- Doesn't use the characters `[0-9]`
- Doesn't branch

Enjoy :)

```
import java.util.LinkedList;class Div{int d(int a){int t=getClass().getName().length();char[]s=Integer.toString(a,t).toCharArray();StringBuilder b=new StringBuilder();LinkedList<Character>l=new LinkedList<>();for(char z:s){l.add(z);}l.removeLast();for(char z:l){b.append(z);}return Integer.valueOf(b.toString(),t);}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 158 characters

```
sub t{use integer;$m=unpack(J,U x 8)^(($n=pop)>0&&3);$p=0;for($t= ~0;$t;$t<<=1){$c=$p&($o=$m&1&&$n);$p=($p^$o)>>1;($p,$c)=($p^$c,($p&$c)<<1)while$c;$m>>=1}$p}
```

This is more than 7 times longer than [the answer by memowe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9107/4065), but it runs faster when the input is large, and supports negative inputs. Now you can divide -2147483648 by 3. This defines a sub. `t(-2147483648)` returns -715827883 because it rounds *down*.

### Division is multiplication!

Division by 3 uses the formula

- n ÷ 3 = n × (2<sup>64</sup> ÷ 3) ÷ 2<sup>64</sup>

with an integer constant to approximate 2<sup>64</sup> ÷ 3. The algorithm multiplies by this constant and drops the lower 64 bits of the 128-bit product. To prevent error, n must be in range for a signed 64-bit integer, and the constant must be

- ⌊2<sup>64</sup> ÷ 3⌋ = 5555 5555 5555 5555<sub>16</sub> if n is negative, or
- ⌈2<sup>64</sup> ÷ 3⌉ = 5555 5555 5555 5556<sub>16</sub> if n is positive.

Multiplication uses an add-and-shift loop. Addition uses bitwise-xor to add and bitwise-and to carry. Shifts preserve the high 64 bits of each 65-bit sum and the final 128-bit product.

### Ungolfed code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# t($n) is floor($n / 3) with only bitwise operations
sub t {
    use integer; # for signed right shift
    my $n = shift;

    # The formula with 64-bit integers is:
    #   $n / 3 = ($n * (1 << 64) / 3) >> 64
    # If this perl has 32-bit integers, then $m and $t get 32-bit
    # values, so the shifts are by 32.

    # $m = (1 << 64) / 3
    #    = 0x5555 5555 5555 5555 if $n < 0
    #    = 0x5555 5555 5555 5556 else
    my $m = unpack 'J', 'UUUUUUUU';  # Unpack 0x55 bytes.
    $n < 0 or $m ^= 3;               # 0x55 ^ 3 == 0x56

    # Multiplication: $p = ($n * $m) >> 64
    my $p = 0;
    for (my $t = ~0; $t; $t <<= 1) { # Loop 64 times.
    if ($m & 1) {
        # Add and shift: $p = ($p + $n) >> 1
        # Shift early to prevent 65-bit overflow.
        my $c = $p & $n;         # Carry.
        $p = ($p ^ $n) >> 1;     # Add by exclusive-or.
        while ($c) {
        ($p, $c) = ($p ^ $c, ($p & $c) << 1);
        }
    }
    else {
        $p >>= 1;
    }
    $m >>= 1;
    }
    return $p;
}

# test program: divide integers
use POSIX qw(floor);
for my $integer (@ARGV) {
    $integer = int($integer);
    my $have = t($integer);
    my $want = floor($integer / 3);
    printf("%d -> %d (%s)\n", $integer, $have,
       $have == $want ? "correct" : "OFF BY @{[$want - $have]}");
}
```

The golfed version has some differences:

- It clobbers global variables.
- It uses the other value of $m if $n is zero.
- It replaces the check `if ($m & 1)` with a new variable `$o=$m&1&&$n`.

Answer (score 1):

## Julia - 29 characters

I'm assuming n as a variable assigned prior to running this line of code.

```
parseint(chop(base(3,n,2)),3)
```

Performs the truncation variant (-35 -> -11 not -12). In the current stable release (0.2.1), this approach only works up to base 36 (for division by 36) as parseint only works for alphanumeric text, but in the 0.3 prerelease (based on the forio.com online REPL), it will work up to 62.

Note that the ",2" at the end is necessary to handle numbers less than 3 (or equivalent) in magnitude, as otherwise chop(base(3,n)) will result in either an empty string (for non-negative values) or "-" (for negative values).

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](//github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
b3Ṗḅ3
```

[Try it online!](//jelly.tryitonline.net#code=YjPhuZbhuIUz&args=OTYz)

Explanation:

```
 b3Ṗḅ3 Main link. Arguments: z
⁸      (implicit) z
  3    3
 b     Convert x to base y
   Ṗ   Trim last element off x
     3 3
    ḅ  Convert x from base y
```

Answer (score 1):

### APL, 11

```
3⊥¯1↓3⊥⍣¯1⊢656
218
```

I'm converting to base 3 and back, removing the last number in the process.
Try it on [tryapl.org](http://tryapl.org/?a=3%u22A5%AF1%u21933%u22A5%u2363%AF1%u22A2656&run)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>31</s> <s>38</s> 29 chars

```
print(eval(input()+"%c3"%47))
```

Edited to add a print statement.

Edited to avoid use of `int` call.

Kind of cheating. Eval will evaluate and return any operations passed as a string as if it were code. chr() converts an int to the character with that ASCII value, and 47=/. Pass in the / with standard string formatting.

Comment: This looks great! It's not cheating.

Comment: This is invalid as it is for the lack of print statement, sorry. Simple fix though, just add a print statement. Also, you can make it python2 and skip the 'int()' part.

Comment: I only say 'cheating' because it does actually use the division operator, it's just a bit hidden.

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, <s>74</s> 57 bytes

Improved upon an [earlier](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6902/59617) answer, I'm not sure if I should post this as my own answer or just comment on the original. But this is significantly different way of generating the sequence `[0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...]`.

```
#(let[r(nth(flatten(for[i(range)][i i i]))(Math/abs %))](if(> % 0)r(- r)))
```

**Edit** after 1.5 years :D

```
#((if(> % 0)+ -)(nth(for[i(range)j[i i i]]j)(max(- %)%)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), 6 bytes

```
ri3:ip
```

```
r grabs input
i converts to integer
3 pushes 3 on the stack
: does float division
i converts to integer
p prints it
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOLcn//78o09gqs@D/f0MDAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 19 bytes

```r
mean(c(scan(),0,0))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Pzc1MU8jWaM4GUhp6hjoGGhq/te1tOT6DwA)

Saw this method above in another language, and easily implemented it in R. And it gives precise answers. Works for positive and negative inputs.

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 18 bytes

```r
gl(x<-scan(),3)[x]
```

Slightly shorter solution that only works for positive numbers and performs "actual" integer division.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Pz1Ho8JGtzg5MU9DU8dYM7oi9r@l5X8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 19 bytes

```perl6
{Rat.new($_,3).Int}
```

A rational number in Perl 6 is literally defined as a numerator over a denominator.  So passing it 7 creates the fraction <sup>7</sup>/<sub>3</sub> .  That fraction is then coerced to an Int.  This should work for all ℤ .

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwvzoosUQvL7VcQyVex1hTzzOvpPa/NRdXcSJIAVBQUyEtv0hB19BAT8/QgOs/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>82</s> 74 bytes

<sup>-8 bytes thanks to mazzy</sup>

```powershell
param($n)'-'[$n-ge0]+(-join(0..$n|?{$_}|%{1})-replace111,0-replace1|% Le*)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/b8gsSgxV0MlT1NdVz1aJU83PdUgVltDNys/M0/DQE9PJa/GvlolvrZGtdqwVlO3KLUgJzE51dDQUMcAzqlRVfBJ1dL8X8vFpaFrpqdnpglUraQSr2@sYKugoqGmkqagEq@pVPsfAA)

Bug-fix of [Joseph Alcorn's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7063/78849) to handle negatives correctly.

[83 bytes to have 0 instead of -0](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/b8gsSgxV0MlT1NdVz1aJU83PVXXKFZbQzcrPzNPw1BPLzo3sSQj1srKMakYpKpGtdqwVlO3KLUgJzE51dDQUMcAztHU80nNSy/J@F/LxaWha6anZwZSrqQSr2@sYKugoqGmkqagEq@pVPsfAA)

Comment: `-0` is not very nice. Powershell knows how to make ranges with with negative bounds :)

Comment: @mazzy If you go 1..$n with a negative, you get two extra iterations. 0..$n is an extra tick as well because you can't do 0..--$n(but can probably be fixed with minimal fuss)

Comment: [74 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/b8gsSgxV0MlT1NdVz1aJU83PdUgVltDNys/M0/DQE9PJa/GvlolvrZGtdqwVlO3KLUgJzE51dDQUMcAzqlRVfBJ1dL8X8vFpaFrpqdnpglUraQSr2@sYKugoqGmkqagEq@pVPsfAA "PowerShell – Try It Online") :)

Comment: is `This also applies to incrementing and decrementing operators` means `Do not use incrementing and decrementing operators`? Ok. Then your approach is best.

Comment: @mazzy Yep, those are not to be used.

Answer (score 0):

32 characters in Burlesque:

```
0\/r@{1\/.-<-2\/.-<-}{L[1.>}w!-]
```

assuming the number to divide is already on the stack. (see [here](http://eso.mroman.ch/cgi/burlesque.cgi?q=30%200%5C%2Fr%40%7B1%5C%2F.-%3C-2%5C%2F.-%3C-%7D%7BL%5B1.%3E%7Dw!-%5D) in action).

How does it work? It generates a list of numbers 0..n and then removes one from the left and two from the right until only one number is left. Of course this method only works with numbers that are divisible by 3.

Answer (score 0):

Perl using an eval to compute a string version of x/3.

Perl 5.8 Version

```
print eval join' ','int',$ARGV[0],map{chr}47,51
```

Perl 5.10 Version

```
say print eval join' ','int',$ARGV[0],map{chr}47,51
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the exactly meets the criteria of "without using the / operator". It still uses it, it's just hidden in the code as character 47.

Comment: You are correct, this just hides it.
Either way, my solution isn't nearly as good as memowe's version using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

**perl 23**

```
$_=()=(1x$_)=~/(111)/g
```

usage:

```
> echo 1e4|perl -pe'$_=()=(1x$_)=~/(111)/g'
3333
```

Doesn't work with negatives.

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematica (assorted)

Dividing 9 by 3 (but should work for arbitray input). The second version outputs just the number, while the first will offer additional braces (not sure about what is deemed correct, pick your count):

```
9Inverse[{{3}}]              (*15*)
9Inverse[{{3}}][[1,1]]       (*22*)

LinearSolve[{{3}},{9}]       (*22*)
LinearSolve[{{3}},{9}][[1]]  (*27*)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 28 (Non-competing, only unsigned)

```
?$\<@'\.|!"1.(|{'&.{&.1\()\$
```

[Try It Online!](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=PyRcPEAnXC58ISIxLih8eycmLnsmLjFcKClcJAo&input=MTIz)

Haven't got any Bitwise operators, so either can't join (like BF) or break the rules with increments and decrements.  I chose the latter as I ...

...just want to share the facts that a hexagon is a polygon with 6 sides, and the number 6 has a factor 3. This is an "advantage" to Hexagons so I hope this will be interesting.

### Expanded version

```
   ? $ \ <
  @ ' \ . |
 ! " 1 . ( |
{ ' & . { & .
 1 \ ( ) \ $
  . . . . .
   . . . .
```

`?` gets the input, and `$` skips a mirror then we hit `<` the branch.

If the number is `<=0` it goes to the corner then to `{!@` which prints the "counter" (explained below) and ends the program.

(Else) If it is `>0`,

1. decrement it and increase the counter by 1 (located relatively at
   `{` as left neighbour and goes back with `"`).
2. Step back to the
   right and copy.
3. Step back to the right and copy again.
4. Goes back to the branch after a few reflections.

Anyone who wants to understand how this ends with graphics? I hope there is someone who wants to know more about Hexagony and know why keep stepping back to the right will in turn accumulates the counter. :P

I can't use the operators `+-*/%`.  Can I use `:`? (The integer division) Obviously not - I'll be breaking the rules.  Sadly I am already breaking the rules with increments and decrements.  So I imposed myself to an unintended rule - not using `/` as an operator for reflection :) Whole program is `+-*/%`-free.  May need a side length 5 hexagon to make one that can take care of the negatives...

Oh I just love hexagons.

[Hexagon Edition](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=ICAgPyAkIHwgPAogIEAgJyBcIEggfAogISAiIEUgWCAoIHwKeyAnIEEgRyB7ICYgfAogTyAmIE4gKSBcICQKICAuIC4gLiAuIC4KICAgLiAuIC4gLg&input=MTIz), also 28, another way to get back into the loop.

```
?$|<@'\H|!"EX(|{'AG{&|O&N)\$
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2, 16 bytes (Joke Answer)

```
print input()//3
```

`//` is not the same as `/`, the division operator. `//`, a token in and of itself, is the floor-division operator. Example: `4.5 // 2 == 2`. Note that this answer exploits a loophole in the question, and can be considered a joke. However, it is within the technical rules because the question says you cannot use the `/` **operator**. Although this answer uses the character "/", it never uses it as an operator.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 61 bytes

```
from numpy import*;f=lambda x:int(base_repr(x,base=3)[:-1],3)
```

This doesn't win, but I think it's a clever method that hasn't been used in the other Python entries, so I'm posting it here.

Comment: if using numpy `import numpy;print(int(numpy.mean([x,0,0])))` for 44?

Answer (score 0):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/)/MATLAB, 7 bytes

```matlab
@(x)3\x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0LTOKbif5pGaWZeibGRhqWm5n8A)

I'm not entirely sure whether or not this would count as cheating. It's not using one of the specifically listed operators (+-%/*). MATLAB has a right divide operator which divides a number on the right by a number on the left.

I'll delete this answer if the consensus that it is cheating.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 21 bytes

```ruby
->n{3.step(n,3).size}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6v2livuCS1QCNPx1hTrzizKrX2f4FCWrSZaSwXmDaD0uax/wE)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (bitwise), 92 bytes

Because this is interview question, I assume they expected to see implementation of division using bitwise operations, not tricks with strings. 
So here it is. Works for negative values as well.

```javascript
f=(a,b)=>b?f(a^b,(a&b)<<1):a
x=prompt(s=0)
while(y=x>>2)s=f(s,y),x=f(x&3,y)
alert(f(s,x==3))
```

Comment: _bitwise operations, not tricks with strings_ -- is your solution not the one heavily dependent on bitwise operations?

Comment: @JonathanFrech it is. As I mentioned in answer, I think that what was initial interview question all about.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 29 chars

`eval(str(x)+chr(47)*2+str(3))`

first golf, feels cheaty to me but here goes!

other one for 44:

`import numpy;print(int(numpy.mean([x,0,0])))`

Comment: Technically, you're still using a forbidden operator, it's just not visible in your source.

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart However, this viewpoint opens a deep rabbit hole: it is unlikely that the chosen Python interpreter does not contain a forbidden character, making it  -- again -- technically use one ...

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 66 bytes

```php
<?='-'[$argn<=>0].intval(substr(base_convert($argn,10,3),0,-1),3);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt5WXVc9WiWxKD3PxtbOIFYvM6@kLDFHo7g0qbikSCMpsTg1Pjk/ryy1qEQDrErH0EDHWFPHQEfXUBPIsP7/X9fQyOBffkFJZn5e8X9dNwA)

Divides by lobbing off the least significant digit in the base 3 representation of the original number.  The result is truncated (`10/3 = 3`), works with negative numbers and uses the PHP spaceship operator.

Answer (score 0):

## [ReRegex](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ReRegex), 22 bytes

```
a(_*)\1\1_*/$1/a#input
```

Takes IO in the form of unary `_`s via STDIN.

Simple program, matches three chunks of _'s as greedily as possible, and dumps out the first group. Remaining _'s are also matched away.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otSk1Prfj/P1EjXkszxjDGMF5LX8VQP1E5M6@gtOT//3hUAAA)

Answer (score -1):

## Scheme, 95 <strike>110</strike> bytes

```
(define (h n)
  (length
   (let l ((a (iota n)))
     (if (> (length a) 2)
         (cons 1 (l (cdddr a)))
         '()))))
```

My original attempt using base conversion:

```
(define (g n)
  (string->number
   (list->string
    (reverse
     (cdr
      (reverse
       (string->list
        (number->string n 3))))))
   3))
```

I can't think of a better way of removing the last character from the string.